# Uncaught TypeError during proj4 transformation

Tags: openlayers-2, proj

I get:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined at proj4js-combined.js:2720

While executing this code (transforming polygon from one system to another):

```
Proj4js.defs['EPSG:3765'] = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=16.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs';

var source = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:3765');
var wgs84 = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4326');

var polygon = Proj4js.transform(source, wgs84, features[0].geometry.Polygon);       

gmlLayer.addFeatures(polygon);
map.addLayer(gmlLayer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be referencing Polygon after geometry.

The code should be

```
var polygon = Proj4js.transform(source, wgs84, features[0].geometry);
```